How to use a specific font and font weight combination in a LaTeX document in MacOS
I am using the latest version of MacOS and have installed the latest version of MacTeX. Also, I use Visual Studio Code to write my tex code and have installed the LaTeX Workshop extension to essentially be able to instantly convert my .tex to .pdf, by clicking the green play button at the right corner, and view the pdf inside Visual Studio Code.
I visited https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Serif?query=noto+serif&subset=greek&script=Grek to download and install the "Noto Serif" font to my system. Using the following code:
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}
This is Noto Serif.
\end{document}

inside Visual Studio Code, everything seems to work fine. However, I haven't found a way to specify the "thickness" of the font (e.g. Light, Bold, etc.). If I replace "Noto Serif" with "Noto Serif Bold", I get a fatal error.

I located the tex fonts at "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/google/noto" and so I am using the code:
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Path = /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/google/noto,
  UprightFont = *-Light.ttf,
  BoldFont = *-Bold.ttf,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic.ttf
]{NotoSerif}

\begin{document}
This is some text.
\end{document}

which still gives me an error. Namely, "Font TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/n/10=[/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/google/notoNotoSerif-Light.ttf]/OT at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.".

please copy-paste the error message into your question. which fonts did you install exactly? there are lots of Noto fonts ....

I clicked the "Get Font" button in the right corner from the link "https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Serif?query=noto+serif&subset=greek&script=Grek" and then I clicked the download button. I unzipped .zip which I downloaded and installed the 2 .ttf packages, one was for Regular and the other was for Italic.
The error message I get is "Recipe terminated with error".

NotoSerif-Refular.ttf is part of texlive so you probably didn't need to install it from google fonts

"Recipe terminated with error" is not a tex error that is just your editor reporting that some (unshown) error occurred.

Should also note "\textbf{}" doesn't change the text to bold at all. The text stays the same as without it.

Found the error in the output: "Package fontspec Error: The font "Noto Serif Black" cannot be found.".

It's pretty frustrating that "Noto Serif" actually loads some variant of the font, and then I just can't specify the thickness of the font.

by default texlive should have NotoSans-Black.ttf   and 45 other variants in $ ls /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/google/noto
(replacing  /usr/local/texlive/2024/ by wheveer your tex tree is installed)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

it sounds like you want Noto Serif variable font from https://fonts.google.com/selection?vfquery=noto+serif  if you use the variable font you can use [Weight=100] to get a light version

presumably NotoSans-Black is sans rather than serif, but NotoSerif-Black.ttf and 17 other variants are also part of TL. (these aren't the variable font @DavidCarlisle mentioned, though.)

@cfr er yess thanks I copied the wrong name:-)

you shouldn't install anything yourself under /usr/local/texlive/2024/ because that tree is reserved for TeX Live's distribution tree. use /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ instead. you will likely have to create the necessary directory structure if you've not used it before. (but don't do this for fonts you've already got ...)

Path = /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/google/noto/,

I also use the latest version of MacOS along with MacTeX2024 (with all updates installed). Under LuaLaTeX, I employ \textbf to specify bold and \textit to specify italics.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newcommand\hw{Hello World. Γειά σου Κόσμε. Привіт Світ. Chào thế giới.}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
\hw
\textit{\hw}
\textbf{\hw}
\textbf{\textit{\hw}}
\end{document}


Addendum: Since Noto Serif comes in nine [9!] weights -- Thin, ExtraLight, Light; Regular, Medium, SemiBold; Bold, ExtraBold, Black -- it's worth using \newfontfamily directives to set up desired weight combinations. E.g.,
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[%
      UprightFont    = * Regular,
      ItalicFont     = * Italic,
      BoldFont       = * SemiBold,
      BoldItalicFont = * SemiBold Italic
      ]
\newfontfamily{\NotoSerifThin}{Noto Serif}[%
      UprightFont    = * Thin,
      ItalicFont     = * Thin Italic,
      BoldFont       = * Light,
      BoldItalicFont = * Light Italic
      ]
\newfontfamily{\NotoSerifBold}{Noto Serif}[%
      UprightFont    = * Bold,
      ItalicFont     = * Bold Italic,
      BoldFont       = * Black,
      BoldItalicFont = * Black Italic
      ]

and then use the directives \NotoSerifThin and \NotoSerifBold to switch to the "thin" and "bold" font groupings.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[%
      UprightFont    = * Regular,
      ItalicFont     = * Italic,
      BoldFont       = * SemiBold,
      BoldItalicFont = * SemiBold Italic
      ]
\newfontfamily{\NotoSerifThin}{Noto Serif}[%
      UprightFont    = * Thin,
      ItalicFont     = * Thin Italic,
      BoldFont       = * Light,
      BoldItalicFont = * Light Italic
      ]
\newfontfamily{\NotoSerifBold}{Noto Serif}[%
      UprightFont    = * Bold,
      ItalicFont     = * Bold Italic,
      BoldFont       = * Black,
      BoldItalicFont = * Black Italic
      ]

\newcommand\hw{Hello World. Γειά σου Κόσμε. Привіт Світ. Chào thế giới.}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
\hw
\textbf{\hw}

\medskip
\NotoSerifThin
\hw
\textbf{\hw}

\medskip
\NotoSerifBold
\hw
\textbf{\hw}

\end{document}


For me in the code:
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}

\obeylines

This is some text.\\
\textbf{This is some text.}

\end{document}

they are exactly the same.

@euvageloskazazis - Are you free to use LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX to compile your document?

Thanks to Mico, I switched from xelatex to lualatex and this solved it for me. More specifcally, in the code:
\textbf{This is some text.} \end{document}

"\textbf" now works, whereas before the text inside "\textbf" remained the same as without it.
